# Unable to play music in elementary OS default music player

Tags: music

I'm unable to play music in the default music player. Every time I need to import files it shows a red dash as shown in screenshot.

[image: Imgur]

**EDIT**:

I already have `ubuntu-restricted-extras` installed.

Comment: I was having the same problem. The only way I was able to listen to my music again was by installing a third-party audio player, audacious. I have not had that problem since. That is what I would recommend for you.

Comment: could you provide some (detailed) info about how you imported the files? where are they located, do you have the 'copy files to Library' or 'keep Music folder organised' options on or off?

Comment: 1.I imported files from gear symbol at top right corner.2.The files located in hard disk partition.3.All options are in  ON state.

Comment: Cool, were the music files already in the music folder (before you imported them), and have they copied there if not?

Comment: sorry-I misunderstand your second Q.Well,No the music files are in separate partition and I Import them by changing location in preferences...@TimothyGray

Comment: ok, do you want them kept in ~/Music or in the separate partition?

Comment: I want to keep them in separate partition since I have 3 OS in my system,I have to keep in separate partition to use when I boot to any OS. =)@TimothyGray

Comment: What you could try is making a symbolic link to the other harddrive. An symbolic link is essentially an shortcut, but most applications will treat it like a normal folder. the command is `ln -s /path/to/other/hdd/music ~/Music`. Only do this if your other hdd automatically mounts! I would also advice first turning off all the Noise settings to manage your library.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a codec problem. I had the same on elementary live usb. During your installation, did you check the box "install proprietary software"? What is the extention of your music files? Does it works with a .ogg file?

You can install evrithing you might need by installing ubuntu-restricted-extras. Do it from the software center or run :

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

If it still don't work learn about installing the codec for your format, or different ways to do that.

Comment: thanks for reply, I already installed codecs (`ubuntu-restricted-extras`), so its not the issue :)

Comment: Can you click on the red thing? If you leave the mouse above it a long time, does it says somehing? What? Have you tried with other extentions? if it works with an .ogg file I am shure this is a codec problem. Have you tried with vlc or Rythmbox? I think I can help you you need to answer those questions.@Ravan

Comment: thanks, I can't produce error message now( I am outside). vlc working fine.

Comment: any other possible solutions?

Answer (score 1):

I just had this same problem, and the way I solved it was simple.

I imported the files in the ~/Music folder from an external drive with an ntfs filesystem.

And the database that was created was still linking to the external drive.

To fix this was very easy.  If you are comfortable with terminal use, do the following (or use the Files app to open HOME and show hidden files.)

First, close noise.

Then, in a terminal:

```
cd ~/.local/share/noise 
rm database_0_3_1.db
```

You can now exit the terminal, and start Noise again.

If all of the files are already in Music, then just allow noise to import them, and you should be able to play them.

So I am pretty certain that there is no need to reinstall the restricted-extras package, unless of course you didn't install it when you were installing elementary for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Try importing your music again. If you're importing the same music, a prompt will appear saying that the files are already in the library. Ignore it. Try to play a song. The app should work by then. Unfortunately, you have to do this every time you turn on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue myself.  My music data was stored on a seperate HDD within my computer.  Every time I power on my computer I have to open the main directory of that drive in the 'Files' application.

Comment: use GNU disks to set up automount