# Freya Asus X55C mp3 is not playing

Tags: release-freya

Recently I liked to install [freya](http://elementary.io) instead of Ubuntu.  But whenever I open  music player and import mp3 songs.  It shows file corrupted. And delete it.  But in my music are all playing well in all other play forms.

Comment: does it similar to [this](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2504/unable-to-play-music-in-elementary-os-default-music-player)?

Comment: its not importing. it shows the mp3 files are corrupted  and asking to delete or ignore it.

Comment: did you get solution. ?  can you help me

Comment: I have done fresh install of freya again recently, I too experiencing this error

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem solved after installing `ubuntu-restricted-extras`

Open terminal and run the command:

```
 sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

*Note*: Use <kbd>Tab</kbd> when EULA appear in terminal.

Comment: let me check it.

Comment: let me know status, If solved accept @Akelya :)

Comment: still its showing the same error.

Comment: is there any pack available for music and videos

Comment: "Same error" Can you post screenshot @Akelya

Comment: I think this should solve the problem, from where you are importing files?