# ElementaryOS music player doesn't open when CD is inserted

Tags: release-juno, music

Hullo,

I've just installed Elementary, and upon inserting a CD, I found that I can't open the music player. It starts, but the window only persists for a moment. Leaving it open before inserting the disc closes the application.

Due to [this thread](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2504/unable-to-play-music-in-elementary-os-default-music-player), I thought this might be a codec problem, so I installed `ubuntu-restricted-extras`, and also tried deleting the database in `~/.local/share/noise/`, to no avail.

I've found that I can play CDs with the Clementine music player, but I'd rather use the default application if possible.

I'd be grateful for any help in resolving this, or if this is an unknown bug, a place to submit a bug report.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can file a bug report by opening an issue at the relevant GitHub repository. Or even better, contribute to the one already opened here which I just found: https://github.com/elementary/music/issues/437